# Convert unicode series from a webpage to Chinese characters with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

This is my first experience with unicode, and also with escaping and I'm over my head. The source is a website's pull-down menu and I want to generate a text list of all the items using Python.

From `&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02` I understand that I need to make something that looks like `u'\u65B0\u5317\u5E02'` in order to see 新北市 when I print it.

However `''.join([s.replace('&#x', '\u') for s in ''.split(';')])` fails:

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape`

and `''.join([s.replace('&#x', '\\u') for s in '&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02'.split(';')])` (double backslash) gives me `'\\u65B0\\u5317\\u5E02'`

**Quesiton:** What expression for `mystring` will make `print(mystring)' show '新北市'

Comment: If this has duplicates, please help to find one that is helpful to someone's who is having their "first experience with unicode, and also with trapping". *Thanks!* I've searched already and was not able to find any that I could apply here.

Comment: What exactly is "trapping", I'm not familiar with that term.  Do you mean scraping?

Comment: @MarkRansom that's funny but no, I need to register for something in a country where I can not speak the language, and find a location in my neighborhood, and the website is not google translating, especially not the dropdown menu. This way I can get the names of the locations in Chinese characters, then paste those into google translate all at once and find the best place to go. I think your term "scraping" is not appropriate for this one-time attempt to get a website translated for personal use. It's also an opportunity to learn more Python.

Comment: Well your term trapping still makes no sense to me, you'd have been better off leaving it out of the question entirely.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ah, it's "escaping", perhaps I picked up the term "trapping" decades ago in another context? I've made an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you're dealing with are really HTML entities, you can simply parse the input with `html.unescape`:

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02'))
```

This outputs:

```
新北市
```

Comment: Yes, I should have simply *a priori* assumed there'd be an html library somewhere and looked for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the string to bytes and then decode it with the `unicode-escape` encoding:

```
''.join(s.replace('&#x', r'\u') for s in '&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02'.split(';')).encode().decode('unicode-escape')
```

Comment: Yay, there's my \\u without the \\u! The magic is in the `r`-  can you help me find a link to what that is so I can read further about it? *Thanks!*

Comment: String literals prefixed with `r` are called raw strings, as documented in the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

Comment: @uhoh it was the `'\u'` that was generating your error in the first place, that's not a valid Python string.  But even with that fixed you were only halfway there.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes halfway there is on the way to "there". It's called *learning*.

Comment: @uhoh nothing wrong with learning, it's a noble pursuit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another way, converting the numbers directly to characters.

```
>>> ''.join(chr(int(s.lstrip('&#x'),16)) for s in '&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02'.split(';'))
'新北市'
```

Comment: Now this is really teaching! Rather than unicode being a magical language spoken by unicorns, I can see it's just a fancy way to write numbers and bytes; [26032, 21271, 24066] and ['0b110010110110000', '0b101001100010111', '0b101111000000010']

Comment: Although if the string was `&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02;` instead of `&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02` you'd get a Value Error.

Comment: If we have `zh = "&#x65B0;&#x5317;&#x5E02;"` then maybe something like `''.join(chr(int(s.lstrip('&#x'),16)) for s in f'{zh[:-1] if zh[-1] == ";" else zh}'.split(';'))`

Comment: @Andj good point, although this code was never meant to be robust; I was just illustrating a technique.  A simple `.rstrip(';')` would have been easier than your f-string composition too.

Comment: @MarkRansom, true, `.rstrip(';')` would be much better.